# Como fazer WHILE em PL/SQL

Tags: oracle

Preciso efetuar um `WHILE` em SQL. Segue o código que já tentei

```
DECLARE CONT INT;
SET CONT=0;

WHILE CONT < 3
BEGIN
SELECT CONT   
SET  CONT = CONT +1;
END;
```

O erro que surge é o seguinte:

> ```
> Erro a partir da linha : 1 no comando - DECLARE CONT INT; SET CONT=0;    
> WHILE CONT < 3 BEGIN SELECT CONT    SET  CONT = CONT +1; END; Relatório de
> erros - ORA-06550: linha 2, coluna 9: PLS-00103: Encontrado o símbolo "="
> quando um dos seguintes símbolos era esperado:
>
>   := . ( @ % ; not nulo faixa default caractere
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action:
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo pelo relatório de erros que você colocou você esta usando o Oracle e a sintax dele é um pouco diferente para escrever um while.

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
DECLARE CONT INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
 WHILE CONT < 3 LOOP
   SET CONT := CONT + 1;
 END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

DECLARE CONT INT;
SET CONT=0;

WHILE CONT < 3 DO
BEGIN
SELECT CONT
SET  CONT = CONT +1;
END WHILE;

Em MYSQL

Comment: A pergunta é sobre PL/SQL e Oracle, e não MySQL.